# No logro hacer Binding a un UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, usercontrol

Recurro de nuevo a Uds porque se me presentó un pequeño problema, ya les explico para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Construí un UserControl en WPF C#, en él tengo un Label y una Imagen enmarcados en un cuadro, le agregue que pudiera configurar ciertas características como el FontSize, HorizontalAlignment, el Texto del Label y la visibilidad (Visible, Hidden, Collapsed).

El UserControl funciona perfectamente si agrego todos los valores de los campos en la clase pública de la siguiente manera:

```
public Products()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     BoxText TxtAtt = new BoxText();
     TxtAtt.TextCont = "Producto X";
     TxtAtt.TextFontSize = 8;
     TxtAtt.TextVisible = Visibility.Visible
}
```

Igualmente funciona bien si lo hago en el XAML:

```
<control:BoxText TextCont="Producto Y" TextFontSize="8" TextHorizontal="Left" TextVisible="Visible"/>
```

Pero al momento de trabajarlo con MVVM y hacer el Binding no me hace los cambios:

```
<control:BoxText TextCont="{Binding TxtAtt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextFontSize="{Binding TxtFont, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

En mi ViewModel tengo:

```
public class vmAttribute : Base
{   
    private string txtAtt;
    
    public string TxtAtt
    {
        get { return txtAtt; }
        set
        {
             txtAtt = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TxtAtt));
        }
    }

    private int txtFont;
    
    public int TxtFont
    {
        get { return txtFont; }
        set
        {
             txtFont = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TxtFont));
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _ckAddAttib;

    public DelegateCommand ckAddAttrib
    {
        get { return _ckAddAttib; }
    }
    
    public vmAttribute()
    {
         _ckAddAttib = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
              TxtAtt = "Producto Z";
              TxtFont = 8;
        });
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La palabra "Texto" es el valor por defecto que tiene mi Label en el UserControl.

Mi DataContext está bien porque tengo un button configurado con un binding a mi ViewModel y trabaja perfectamente, cada vez que lo presiono va y ejecuta lo que se encuentra acá _ckAddAttib = new DelegateCommand((), pero los valores del UserControl no cambian.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para que me aclaren que me falta hacer o que estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas Gracias....

Comment: Creo que deberías revisar un poco los conceptos, tu *user control* no debe ser parte del ViewModel, el viewModel se debería enlazar con tu user control solo en xaml, intenta retirar BoxText del viewModel, solo enlaza lo que necesitas en tu user control

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, haré la prueba retirando el BoxText de la VM y le comento

Comment: Gracias probé tu sugerencia retirando el BoxText de la VM y en esta la declaré como un string y lo enlacé al UserControl en al XAML pero nada, sigue sin funcionar, la cruz que ves en el UserControl la uso para cerrar el cuadro y si funciona perfectamente, pero el cambio del texto por Binding no lo hace.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y colocar el cambio que realizaste y asi poder ayudarte

Comment: Listo, Ya coloqué las modificaciones que hice en el ViewModel y el en control del XAML para el binding, en el VM declaré dos campos, TxtAtt como string para el label del UserControl y el TxtFont para el tamaña del mismo, pero aún así no funciona, no se si tiene que ver que hay como un doble binding, el que hay entre el UserControl y la ventana para acceder a sus controles y el que tiene la ventana y el VM, creo que allí es el problema y es lo que no se como resolver

Answer (score 0):

### **Ya pudo resolverlo.**

Acá les explico que hice para que si alguien se le presenta el mismo dilema sepa cómo resolverlo.
Descubrí que la forma de hacerlo funcionar no es establecer el **DataContext** del **UserControl** y, en su lugar, usar **ElementName** y darle un nombre **X:Name** al **UserControl**:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.BoxText""
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="Boxtxt"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

        <Grid>
           <Border CornerRadius="5">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=Boxtxt, Path=TextHorizontal}" 
                           Content="{Binding ElementName=Boxtxt, Path=TextCont}"
                           FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Boxtxt, Path=TextFontSize}"
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Boxtxt, Path=TextVisibility}" />
                    <Image Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Source="/Resources/Icons/Dark/close.png" />
               </StackPanel>
          </Border>
      </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

La implementación de esta UserControl es trivialmente simple:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{        
    public partial class BoxText : UserControl
    {
        public string TextCont
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextContProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextContProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextCont", typeof(string), typeof(BoxText), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
 
        public double TextFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TextFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextFontSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(BoxText), new UIPropertyMetadata((double)12));

        private static HorizontalAlignment DefaultTextHorizontal = new HorizontalAlignment();

        public HorizontalAlignment TextHorizontal
        {
            get { return (HorizontalAlignment)GetValue(TextHorizontalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextHorizontalProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextHorizontalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextHorizontal", typeof(HorizontalAlignment), typeof(BoxText), new UIPropertyMetadata(DefaultTextHorizontal));
 
        public BoxText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el XAML:

```
<control:BoxText Margin="5" TextCont="{Binding TxtAtt}" TextFontSize="{Binding TxtFont}" />
```

Y listo, funciona de mil maravillas…..

Espero que les sirva